# Excel vba CopyFromRecordset doesn't paste cell with date format

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 Excel Files , 1st where people can modify and upload new information and the 2nd is a data base where I put all the information when the other excel have been uploaded.

The problem begins when for example I put from another Excel a new row with information into my data base, and when I open the 1st excel, my code have to CopyFromRecordset in order to bring all the information from the data base and shows in the 1st excel. When this happens the code paste all the information however it doesn't paste two cells that contains date information, it show empty, I don't know how to fix it.

I was looking where the problems comes, and When I add information to the data base, and if I open this data base, put on the cells that contain the new information with the date information, I press "F2" and "enter", At this time when I CopyFromRecordset from the data base to the 1st excel it works, and copy those 2 cells.

I hope you can help me guys, because as you know it's suppose to not open the data base and do that.

I past here the code:

1st is when I add new information in the 1st excel and put on the data base:

```
Public objFSO, objFile As Object
Public bdFile, ConnString As String

Sub SyncBD()
    bdFile = Sheet3.Range("O2").Value 'This is when I put the rute of the file (Data Base)
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(bdFile)
        Kill (bdFile)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BDinhibSCE").Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs bdFile, FileFormat:=51
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

The 2nd part is when there is new information in the data base and I want to bring from the data base to the 1st excel.

```
Public conn As New ADODB.Connection
Public record As New ADODB.Recordset
Public cmd As New ADODB.Command
Sub SyncBD2()
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
        conn.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & Sheet3.Range("O2").Value & >";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;"";"
        record.Open "select*FROM[BDinhibSCE$]", conn
        Sheet1.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset record
        record.Close
        conn.Close
End Sub
```

Here is the screenshot of the data base

As you can see in the column "Fecha de inhibición" I put there a date format, this is the date that don't paste on the excel 1 once I run the second part of the code until I click on the cell with new information and press "F2" + "Enter".

It's important to say that this happen only when I insert a new row, and only with that cell that contains date information.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the layout of you data in the 2nd Excel file?

Comment: It's Sunday and few people around. So excuse me for guessing:- CopyFromRecordset essentially deals in strings. So, perhaps the problem can be cured by specifying `Value2` as data source instead of `Value`, and perhaps you need to ensure that the dates are in string format at source.

Comment: Can you make your database in a real database application? Even Access may be better  than storing in Excel. I know it doesn't directly solve your problem, but it may help in the long run.

Comment: Hey @DecimalTurn I just upload the screenshot.

Comment: @Variatus Thanks for the advice, but I just try and it didn't solve the problem, it's still not pasting those 2 cells.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Ok I'll try to do it, I'll let you know how it works.